# Rails insert automatically my code into body tag not into head tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did it in application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>

     <%if @hasAdsense == true%>
     <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-64xxxxxxxxxxx" async 
      src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
     <%end%>
  
  </head>

  <body>
     <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I see a page with chrome developer tools ,it's automtically inserted in body not in head.

so html code of page where `@hasAdsense==true` looks like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-64xxxxxxxxxxx" 
      async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why this happens, but google bot inspect Adsense script in `head` tag,
so I think this can cause problem so that I can't use Adsense script in my website.

is there a way let rails not insert automatically adsense script into body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have

```
<%if @hasAdsense == true%>
     <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-64xxxxxxxxxxx" async 
      src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<%end%>
```

in any other views, because it might come from the `yield`.

We probs need a little more info here, is `@hasAdsense` a boolean value (can you confirm by showing your controller or checking on the page directly)? does this happen with other content? so if you made a `if` statement with `<title>Hello World</title>` does that render in the body as well?

Comment: Wow, with `title` , it works. I don't know why this happens, and I'm still having some problems ,but it doesn't appear in `body` at least . thank you.